# Group_by (dplyr) with one factor as column

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, summarization

In the following dummy data set, I would like to create a summary table grouping over three variables. So far, I used `dplyr`.
However, I would like to have the values of r as the column names, and the x1 and x2 valuesas the row names, with the respective cells filled by values from m.
What could be a solution?

```
r <- rep(seq(1,10,1),10)
x1 <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
x2 <- rbinom(100, 2, 0.5)
y <- rnorm(100, 10, 5)

df <- data.frame(r,x1,x2,y)

library(dplyr)

View(df %>% 
  group_by(x1,x2,r) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(y))
)
```

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse);df %>% group_by(r, x1, x2) %>% summarise(m = mean(y)) %>% spread(r, m) %>% unite(x, x1, x2) %>% column_to_rownames('x')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired output you basically have to transform from long to wide fromat, using x1 and x2 as grouping variables. Function spread() will do the job:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(x1,x2,r) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(y)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  spread(key = r, value = m,-x1, -x2)
```

Comment: I get an error in the spread; I think you do not need -x1, -x2.  The `ungroup` and `select` are also not needed.  Try just `df %>%
  group_by(x1, x2, r) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(y)) %>%
  spread(r, m)`

Comment: ungroup() is always a good practice when you make more operation than single group_by, select() in this case is optional.